# Dockerfile for windows container-Java-maven-chrome

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I have installed docker for windows server 2016 and it is working fine. However, I am struggling to write a Dockerfile for windows. Can someone translate the below dockerfile to be able to run in windows?? I am trying to build an image that has java8, maven and chrome and chrome driver installed. However, windows based docker daemon has issues with apt-get, wget etc etc

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk

#Install Maven

RUN apt-get update && \apt-get install -y maven && \apt-get clean

# Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

# install chromedriver
#RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip

RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/


copy ..
```